# mysql: what does "You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A" mean after doing "use my-database"?

Tags: mysql

When I select a database:

```
use db_name
```

it displays:

```
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first "use" command after login, MySQL scans database, tables and columns name for auto completion. If you have many db, tables it could take a while.

To avoid that, launch your client with the `-A` option (or `--no-auto-rehash`), e.g.,

```sh
mysql -A
```

Answer (score 2):

That is auto-completion.

If you write up a query, then the SQL tool can help you with that by completing the table and columns names.

To do so it has to get all tables at the beginning, which can take a few seconds. So you have the options to turn that feature off to start faster but don't get auto-completion then.

The SQL tool has a hotkey for completion. So if you write

```
select * from myTabl
```

and hit the completion hotkey, then it completes the query to

```
select * from myTablename
```

If it finds a table starting with the string you typed in.